# How to get datavalues in sequelize with `findAll()` and without `raw:true`?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i want to get datavalues when iam using findAll() in sequelize without using raw:true

```
        Activities.findAll({
         include: [
         {       
           all: true         
          }   
         ],  
       })
        .then(activities => {   
        });
```

Comment: If I remember correctly. findAll returns an array that each element has his own dataValues...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without `raw:true` , you have to loop through each object and get value out of it that something like this :

```
Activities.findAll({
    include: [{
        all: true
    }],
}).then(activities => {
    return activities.map( activity => el.get({ plain: true }) );
});
```

**OR**

`raw : true` , produce the `.` name when include is used , that issue can be solved by `nest : true`

```
Activities.findAll({
    raw : true ,
    nest: true , // <--- The issue of raw true, will be solved by this
    include: [{
        all: true
    }],
}).then(activities => {
    console.log(activities);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solve without using `row: true`

```
let rows = await Activities.findAll();
rows = JSON.stringify(rows);
rows = JSON.parse(rows);
```

rows only get data